# VS2015 debugging on remote machine, Connection always fails

Tags: visual-studio, win-universal-app, remote-debugging

When follow the tutorial [Run Windows Store apps on a remote machine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh441469.aspx#BKMK_Starting_the_Remote_Debugger_Monitor),Visual Studio 2015 can't connect to the remote debugging tools.
VS2015 finds the remote machine, and it can be selected. However when you will try to run the application on the remote machine, the Remote debugger will simply say "Connection from XXX failed".
Neither it, nor visual studio provide any clue as to what happened.

[image: Selecting the remote machine]

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the tutorial links an old version of remote debugger.Current version can be found at their [Download Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48155). 
Up to date guide:
[Deploying and debugging Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt613243.aspx).
It seems to be Microsoft's custom to have multiple, mutually contradictiong versions of the same documentation.